# Regex redacted account details from text in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, ocr, python-re

I have a multipage pdf bank statement and I am using tesseract OCR to convert it to a dataframe. I have the redacted account number in a few lines across the pdf . Consider the following lines to be 3 splits:

```
'ACCOUNT TYPE A/C. BALANCE (I) | FIXED DEPOSITS (LINKED) BAL. (II) TOTAL BALANCE (I+!l) NOMINATION',`
```

`'Savings A/c XXXXXXXX1002 4,58,636.08 0.00 4,58,636.08 Not Registered',`

```
'TOTAL 4,58,636.08 0.00 4,58,636.08',
```

The last 4 numbers might change but will always be integers and the length of the string will always be 12. I want to extract this bit: XXXXXXXX1002.
I tried

```
for line in splits:
if re.search(r'^[A-Z].*([0-9]{4}$)',line):
    AC = line
```

But it did not work.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: see my answer, if its not correct let me know, show us your expected output as well

Comment: I just edited the question to help you understand what I am seeking.

Comment: Try `\bXXXXXXXX([0-9]{4})\b` https://regex101.com/r/EiZpTy/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Hi, your way allows me to get the line      'Statement of Transactions in Savings Account XXXXXXXX1002 in INR for the period October 01, 2019 - October 31, 2019'      among all the plits. But I just want to extract     'XXXXXXXX1002'

Comment: @SubhojyotiLahiri See for example https://ideone.com/PBnzNJ

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you so much. I understand this question was naive but I am fairly new to regex and it was a new way for me to create a dataframe fro pdf.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in dataframe just use `extract()` from column where text exist

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ACCOUNT TYPE A/C. BALANCE (I) | FIXED DEPOSITS (LINKED) BAL. (II) TOTAL BALANCE (I+!l) NOMINATION,'
                         'Savings A/c XXXXXXXX1002 4,58,636.08 0.00 4,58,636.08 Not Registered,'
                         'TOTAL 4,58,636.08 0.00 4,58,636.08']
                   })

df['number'] = df['A'].str.extract('Savings A/c (XXXXXXXX[0-9]{4})')

    print(df)

                             A        number
0  ACCOUNT TYPE A/C. BALANCE (I)....  XXXXXXXX1002
```

Comment: I just edited the question to help you understand what I am seeking

Comment: Sorry, it is in a list called splits. And I just want to extract XXXXXXXX1002. But I will try your way out.

Comment: its hard to understand how your input looks like, you should edit your question properly. anyway even if your input looks different, just use my regex, it should be enough